# Can You Modify the Base Image Directly?

Tags: docker

I just started with docker and want to start creating my containers. Most of my containers have the same environment (JAVA, wget, monit, etc.) all on CentOS 6.5. I pulled my CentOS 6.5 base image and wanted to know if it is possible to modify the base CentOS image to have all these environment requirements or do I need to make the change on a container then create my other containers using the one container? It would be nice if I could just modify the base CentOS image itself.

Answer (score 4):

Make your own base image `FROM` the base centos image (I recommend you to use a Dockerfile). Then run your container from this new custom base.

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6.5

RUN yum update -y && yum -y install wget ...
```

Then tag that image

```
docker build -t myown_centos .
```

Next you can create other images from this one.

```
FROM myown_centos

....
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually modify someone else base image but can create your own base image with the help of other base images.

> FROM ubuntu
>  ENV LANG C.UTF-8

Now build you image using docker build and publish it by using docker push command on you docker hub account. Now, you can pull that uploaded image whenever you needed it without wasting your time on setting up the enviroment.

You can also find images on [hub.docker.com](http://hub.docker.com) which have environment path setup in the Dockerfile like the java docker images.

It has pre-enviroment setup in the image itself.

> ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 
>   ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u91
>   ENV CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION 20140324